# Set a SQL Server database column's data type to a class

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I recently made a monopoly game using C# Winforms and now I need to convert it to a web application. I'm using ASP.NET and I'm having some issues with variables being reset on button clicks.

In order to resolve this, I was planning on having all data stored within a SQL Server database whenever it is changed, and then retrieved when needed. The main issue is that I have 2 classes, `Square` and `Player`.

I can handle the data for player fine but each square has a Player associated with it called "Owner". I'm just wondering if there is any way that in the SQL Server database I can set the data type for "Owner" to the "Player" class so that I can save that along with all the other data. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure what your existing database model looks like but I would think you might have entities for `square`, `player`, and a `player_square` association table. The owner of a square could then be indicated with a `owner_player_id` attribute of `square` with a foreign key to `player`.

Comment: That's a good idea, I suppose I could just use an ownerID int, and then just get the data I need from the list of players using that ID

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server was designed for and works best for structured tabular data.  For complex objects, this usually means it takes several records over several tables to represent a single object.

However, what you are trying to do is store a complex object in a single column in SQL Server.  You can do this in SQL Server, by serializing your object to a string (usually XML or JSON) and storing the string representation of your object in an nvarchar(max) column in SQL.  When you fetch the record, deserialize it back into an object.  You lose quite a bit of power in SQL Server when doing this, but if you don't need to manipulate the data within your object server-side, then it works fine (you can do limited XML and JSON processing within SQL server, but from the sounds of what you are doing, you won't need to).

One of the easiest and most popular ways to serialize objects is to use Newtonsoft JSON.  Add the NuGet package for Newtonsoft, and then serialize your objects by calling `string myComplexObjectAsAString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myComplexObject);`.  You can send that string to SQL, and when you get it back, use `MyComplexObjectType myComplexObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyComplexObjectType>(theStringDataThatYouGotFromSqlServer);`